# Get button to hover over image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys i am trying to get my button in bootstrap 3 to overlap my image, i understand the use of z-index 1 but i cant seem to get it to work at all.

HTML:

```css
.btn-warning {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 198, 0, 0.9);
  border: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 26px;
  line-height: 0.428571;
}

.aboutpic {
  margin-bottom: 19px;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutpic">
  <img src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Download CV</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.btn-warning {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: rgba(255,198,0,0.9);
 border: 0;
 padding: 20px;
 border-radius: 26px;
 line-height: 0.428571;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 50%; 
 left: 50%; 
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

You'll need to add a `position: absolute;` and a `z-index: 1` to the button so that it can sit on top of the image.

codepen.io/lauraeddy/pen/KXEwOW

Comment: Just is well i took out top , left and transform and it star right in the middle and was responsive when the browser was shrunk :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the position of `aboutpic` to `relative` and the button to `absolute`, as in the following example.

**UPDATE**

Added style attributes to center the button over an arbitrarily sized image, using `calc(50% - [button width or button height])`.

```css
.btn-warning {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 198, 0, 0.9);
  border: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 26px;
  line-height: 0.428571;
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
}

.aboutpic button {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  left: calc(50% - 60px);
}

.aboutpic {
  margin-bottom: 19px;
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutpic">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Download CV</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked but i had to change  bottom: 149px; and right: 510px; is there a better way to put it in the middle of the image? or is that the best way

Comment: Yes, there is a better way, please see the update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following,

```css
.btn-warning {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255,198,0,0.9);
    border: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 26px;
        line-height: 0.428571;
}
img{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}

.aboutpic{
  position:relative;
}

.first{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}
.second{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  left:20px;
  top:50px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="aboutpic">
   <div class="first">
          <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/377911/pexels-photo-377911.jpeg" class="img-responsive">   
   </div>
  <div class="second">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Download CV</button>  
  </div>

  </div>
```

Hope this helps.